# Bug in showing disputed flags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, disputed-flags, helpful-flags

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262337/i-need-web-hosting-hosting-for-my-startup-and-confuse-between-a-lot-of-hosting-c) in triage today. After reading initial lines, It appeared to be spam (Discussing his website with details of its services in a promotive narrative). So I flagged it as spam. After a while, I realized my mistake and flagged it as off-topic because the guy was asking for recommendations about web-hosting service.

So, Off-topic flag was regarded as helpful while the spam flag was disputed (even though it should have been declined imo). It is shown below:

[image: flag status]

Now when I opened my [helpful flags page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/4029561?group=1&status=2), I could see off-topic flag was there:

[image: helpful flags]

But when I opened my [disputed flags list](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/4029561?group=1&status=4), the spam flag was not there.

[image]

TLDR for multiple flags raised for one question, if one flag was helpful and other one wasn't, the second flag does not show up in its respective category.

Is this a bug?

Comment: You want to look at your [disputed spam flag group](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/4029561?group=2&status=4)

Comment: FWIW I disputed rather than declined because it did look very spammy on my first reading and I'm glad people are alert to stuff like this potentially being spam.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This isn't a bug. Ignoring comments there are three groups that can have flags disputed:

- Spam
- Offensive
- Posts (anything apart from the above and comments)

Each of these has its own distinct helpful/disputed/declined breakdown - so make sure you're choosing the status for the right flag type when checking your history.